# Creating a hibernation partition on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, hibernate

I have a laptop which comes with a 20GB SSD hibernation partition, but I want to install Linux and use half of that SSD drive as a swap partition. In the case that it breaks, during installation, how would I recreate a new hibernation partition?

Comment: I didn't realize moving the hiberfile in Windows from the root of C: was supported short of trickery, huh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a hibernation Partition you can use [This tool](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/downloads/bootitbm_en_trial.zip) and follow this tutorials ! =)

The 0x84 file system ID is commonly used for hibernation partitions. Using BootIt BM, you can assign this ID to a partition and thereby enable the use of that partition by an operating system.

To assign the 0x84 file system ID, follow these steps:

1. Run BootIt BM.
2. Open the Work with Partitions window by clicking the Partition Work
   icon on the BootIt BM desktop.
3. Access the File System text box:

   If the hibernation partition already exists, double-click its entry,
   or select the entry and then click the Properties button. A
   Properties window will appear and will contain a File System text
   box/drop-down list.

   If the hibernation partition does not exist, select the appropriate
   Free Space block and click the Create button. A Create window will
   appear and will contain a File System text box/drop-down list.
4. Put the cursor in the File System text box and enter: **0x84**
5. Make any other changes desired (for example, if you are creating a
   partition, set the desired Size - MB value). Click OK when finished.

Answer (score 2):

First open cmd.exe and type in "`diskpart`"

At the `DISKPART>` prompt, type the following commands:

```
DISKPART>list disk

DISKPART>select disk X
(X is the disk number where you want to create the store partition. Refer to results from “list disk”
for exact disk number. Disk must be an SSD)

DISKPART>detail disk

DISKPART> select Volume Z
(Z is Volume of your store partition. Refer to results from “detail disk” for exact volume number)

DISKPART>set id=84 override
```