# Windows 7 unneeded files

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, temporary-files

I have 60GB SSD, and I had like 10GB of free space, before I installed 1.5GBs of updates. Now I have 1GB. So, where are those win update installation files, and any other temp or unneeded trash files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use the hibernate mode (suspend to disk) you can disable it. That will delete the hidden file `C:\hibernate.sys` which has the size of your main memory.

If you don't want to loose the hibernate mode and you have an additional HDD in your system you can create a special hibernate partition on the HDD.

For more details see [Creating a hibernation partition on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/376593/creating-a-hibernation-partition-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 3):

run cleanmgr.exe should allow you to clean temporary files etc. in your OS disk.

Answer (score 1):

There's a comprehensive [article](http://lifehacker.com/5894838/customize-your-windows-installation-to-create-the-os-of-your-dreams) over at Lifehacker. This solution requires a reinstall though. I don't know if that's something you're willing to do but it could pay major dividends.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner). It has good options to cleanup a lot of temp files related to specific programs.