# Erase or edit contents file of "hiberfil.sys" and "pagefile.sys" on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are hiberfil.sys and pagefile.sys files, and can I safely delete them?](https://superuser.com/questions/360381/what-are-hiberfil-sys-and-pagefile-sys-files-and-can-i-safely-delete-them)

How can I erase or edit the contents of file "hiberfil.sys" and "pagefile.sys" in Windows 7?

Because the first file is about 7 GB and the second file is about 9 GB on my computer. They have occupied a large amount of hard disk space. What can I do?

Comment: You should have googled what those files are before posting a question. You would have found the answer right away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"pagefile.sys" and "hiberfil.sys" are system files, and you cannot delete them in Windows.

1. The page file is "virtual memory" that works like your [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory), but on your hard disk drive. If you make it smaller in size (by going to System -> Settings -> Advanced -> Virtual Memory -> advanced) you decrease system performance.
2. As "tumchaaditya" told, `hiberfil.sys` is also for putting the system into hibernation. You can get rid of it by disabling hibernation.

NOTE: Windows can not work without a page file, so if you delete that from another OS, then it may cause your system to crash (not booting up) or Windows will make another at the first start. So my advice is to not delete them.

Comment: The hiberfil.sys can be "moved" to a separate partition: [Creating a hibernation partition on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/376593/creating-a-hibernation-partition-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

`hiberfil.sys` is required for hibernating(aka hybrid sleep) the system.
You can get rid of this file by disabling hibernate from power options.

`pagefile.sys` is the page memory file.
To know what page memory is, search google for page memory or swap file or pagefile.
It is practically not possible to get rid of this file.
But, you can reduce its size by changing page memory size.
I would recommend against this though.

As for the editing is concerned, I don't think you can edit these files. Even if you could, what exactly do you plan to do with the files?

Answer (score 1):

If you have another operating system installed on your PC you can safely remove the files by logging into that. Otherwise boot into Win7 installation DVD go to repair and select command prompt. You can delete it using command line. Also try using ubuntu live cd.